# i want to redirect the user to dashboard after clicking on the email link sent by email valification, not working, i have to refresh bowser to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    try {
      if (user) {
        if (user.emailVerified === true) {
          // Email is verified, redirect to the dashboard

          if (userData?.user_type === "attendee") {
            navigate("/dashboard");

          } else if (userData?.user_type === "organizer") {
            navigate("/dashboard_organizer");

          } else if (userData?.user_type === "admin") {
            navigate("/admin_dashboard");

          } else {
            displayWarningToast("You have no dashboard");
            console.log("no such user type");
          }
          displaySuccessToast("Email Verified");

        } else {
          displayWarningToast("Email not verified");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error during email verification check:", error);
    }
  });

  // Cleanup the listener when the component unmounts
  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };


}, [navigate, auth, userData?.user_type]);
```

I wanted to redirect the user to dashboard after the listener listens to email click, but it has failed.

Comment: What is `onAuthStateChanged`? Right now you're just defining a function in your useEffect, but it's not getting called anywhere. Hard to tell what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but just guessing that what you want is something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   const onAuthStateChanged = (auth, user) => {
    try {
      if (user) {
        if (user.emailVerified === true) {
          // Email is verified, redirect to the dashboard

          if (userData?.user_type === "attendee") {
            navigate("/dashboard");

          } else if (userData?.user_type === "organizer") {
            navigate("/dashboard_organizer");

          } else if (userData?.user_type === "admin") {
            navigate("/admin_dashboard");

          } else {
            displayWarningToast("You have no dashboard");
            console.log("no such user type");
          }
          displaySuccessToast("Email Verified");

        } else {
          displayWarningToast("Email not verified");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error during email verification check:", error);
    }
  });
  // however you get the user. I can't tell where that's supposed to come from here.
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, user)

}, [navigate, auth, userData?.user_type]);
```

I don't really think you have to worry about a cleanup function since you aren't setting state anywhere in your useEffect callback. That's where you run into problems like setting state on an unmounted component. This isn't a listener it's just a side effect that gets called whenever your dependencies change.